# How to pass an object reference to a Task(TPL)?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have a method that i want to perform in the background using Task. The method however requires a reference to an object as the parameter. However the object is created in the UI thread and therefore i got the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." exception. How should i go about doing this?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SerializeGraphicsLayer(graphicsLayer, fileUrl))
                    .ContinueWith((t) => UpdateSaveOperation(t), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The SerializeGraphicsLayer() method is the one that i want to operate in the background, however, i need to pass in an object reference created in the UI thread to this method...

EDIT:
The method(that is running in the backgound) might throw an exception and the UpdateSaveOperation() method will do the necessary error message in the UI.

I would like to have good exception handling and that is why i chose Task to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A UI object is not a good candidate for use on a background thread. If possible, you can obtain the *values* you need, and *capture* them into your operation:

```
string name = userName.Text; // access values on UI thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => /* something using name, but not the UI control*/ );
```

However, if you need to update values *back* to the UI, you will have to to get back to the UI thread. If *all* you are doing is updating the UI, you might as well not use TPL (it isn't a good fit).

Comment: in the SerializeGraphicsLayer() method, the graphicsLayer object parameter is not a UI control, it is just an object created in the UI thread. I chose the TPL because the method might throw an exception and the Task can wrap the exception back to the UI thread?

Comment: @icube if all you want to do is catch an exception, then `catch` does that. However, to get that message **something** is talking to the UI - maybe an event subscription?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can use Dispatcher class for performing, non UI related heavy tasks that can be easily moved to background thread. For more clarification check out the following article : [Understanding “Dispatcher” in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx)

When invoking methods via Dispatcher, you can pass any object as parameter and in the invoked method, you will have to cast it back into the original type.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where a background task must create an object which later will be displayed by the UI you can first let the UI dispatcher create the object and then pass it back to the background task by using the Dispatcher<T> signature. Example:

```
private Info AddFolderInfoRecursive(string folder)
{
        ....
        return Dispatcher.Invoke<Info>(() =>
        {
            Info info = new Info(folder)
            {
                Size = folderSize,
                NumFolders = numFolders,
                NumFiles = numFiles
            };
            return info;
        }
}
```

The dispatcher then calls the UI, the UI creates the object and grants the caller the right to access the object. This way the background task can access the object safely.